# Java: Possible to use a single for-loop instead of two?

Tags: java, arrays

My code is as below. It first takes input from user and prints it in reverse. I'm new to Java. I achieve this by using two 'for loops' to first iterate through the input and another for-loop to print the numbers in reverse. My question is if there's any way to improve my code - by using just a single loop perhaps? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[n];

    for (int arr_i = 0; arr_i < n; arr_i++) {
        arr[arr_i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    for (int reverse_i = n-1; reverse_i >= 0; reverse_i--) {
        System.out.print(arr[reverse_i]);

        if (reverse_i != 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

An example input:

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

Expected output:

```
4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Don't you need to populate your array before you attempt to go over it in reverse order?

Comment: yes I do by using the Scanner input --> arr[arr_i] = in.nextInt();

Comment: I think you missed my point... What is the end goal here?

Comment: Could you give an example of the input and output?

Comment: @cricket_007 the end goal is to print the received input in reverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` and always insert at `0` index.

> See: [Oracle » JavaDocs » 1.7 » java.lang.StringBuilder.insert(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,%20int))

```
StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();

for (int arr_i = 0; arr_i < n; arr_i++) {
    int i = in.nextInt();
    bld.insert(0, i);
}

System.out.println(bld.toString());
```

Comment: This code doesn't print a blank space after inserting a number. I tried adding bld.insert (0, " "); but this doesn't fulfill the requirement because there shouldn't be an empty space after the last number.

Comment: Just use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt(int) to delete the last char

Comment: Of course there are for loops being used inside of each `StringBuilder.insert(...)` call.

Comment: As OP Posted *My question is if there's any way to improve my code*

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach I found is to use String Builder here:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while (in.hasNext()) {
   stringBuilder.append(in.next());
   if(in.hasNext()) {
     stringBuilder.append(" ");
   }
}

System.out.print(stringBuilder.reverse());
```

Comment: That's still 2 loops.

Comment: Updated my answer for more simple solution with one loop

Comment: @Gray this is doing fine. Why do you think its not reversed? 

As mentioned in question with an example Input:
1 2 3 4
Output is:
4 3 2 1

Comment: Missed the reverse @Ms.Zia.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the requirements of your request, but you do not necessarily have to use an array for this. You can concatenate the inputs into a String in reverse order like so.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    String allNumbers = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int current = in.nextInt();
        allNumbers = current + " " + allNumbers;
    }

    if(allNumbers != ""){
      allNumbers = allNumbers.substring(0,allNumbers.length()-1);
    }

    System.out.println(allNumbers);
}
```

Comment: better to use a StringBuilder as per my answer

Comment: @Scary Wombat Yeah you're right. I think this method will result in an extra blank character (" ") at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

First, you might reverse your elements as you insert them in the array. Then, assuming you are using Java 8+, you could use an `IntStream` instead of a loop and print with a basic Collector. Like,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();
int[] arr = new int[n];
IntStream.range(0, n).forEachOrdered(i -> arr[n - i - 1] = in.nextInt());
System.out.println(IntStream.of(arr).mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Answer (score -1):

Java has inbuilt String method for the same. If your input is a String, you can use the below-

```
String s1 = new String("new");
String s2 = s1.reverse();
System.out.println(s2) // wen
```

Comment: Question isn't completely reversing a string (you missed the spaces)